# Cannot remote (rdp) into EC2 started from aws lambda using boto3::run_instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

When I launch an EC2 instance from a particular AMI via the web console, it works just fine and I can RDP into it no problems.

But when I launch another (identical) instance via an aws lambda, I cannot RDP into the instance

#### Details

Here is the lambda used to launch the instance

```py
import boto3
REGION = 'ap-southeast-2' 
AMI = 'ami-08e9ad7d527e4e95c'
INSTANCE_TYPE = 't2.small' 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    EC2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=REGION)
    init_script = """<powershell>
powershell "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\ScriptToRunDaily.ps1"
aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids 'curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id'
</powershell>"""
    instance = EC2.run_instances(
        ImageId=AMI,
        InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
        MinCount=1,
        MaxCount=1, 
        InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior='terminate', 
        UserData=init_script 
    )
```

I can see the instance start up in the AWS console. Everything looks normal until I go to remote in, where a prompt says 'Initiating remote session' takes ~15 seconds and returns

```
We couldn't connect to the remote PC. Make sure the PC is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled.

Error code: 0x204
```

#### Note

When I click try to connect to the instance through the AWS console, it lets me download an RDP file, however, it doesn't display the option to 'Get Password' as it does if I start the exact same AMI through the console (as opposed to via a lambda)

I suspect I may need to associate the instance with a keypair at launch?

#### Also note

Before creating this particular AMI, I logged in and changed the password, so I really have no need to generate one using the `.pem` file.

Comment: Are you launching in the same public subnet? I don't see you are specifying one in your lambda

Comment: I don't think so. Should I be?

Comment: Try and pass a vpc and subnet, and make sure the subnet is public

Comment: @RodrigoM I can see how to do that from the [boto docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html). However, I don't know where to go or how to get the actual values for `'SubnetId': 'string'` and `'VpcId': 'string'`

Comment: I tried copying the values from a successfully (manually launched) ec2, but no luck. `"Parameter validation failed:\nUnknown parameter in input: \"VpcId\", must be one of: BlockDeviceMappings, ImageId, InstanceType, Ipv6AddressCount, Ipv6Addresses, KernelId, KeyName, MaxCount, MinCount, Monitoring, Placement, RamdiskId, SecurityGroupIds, SecurityGroups, SubnetId, UserData, AdditionalInfo, ClientToken, DisableApiTermination, DryRun, EbsOptimized, IamInstanceProfile, InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior, NetworkInterfaces, PrivateIpAddress, ElasticGpuSpecification` etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to add `SecurityGroupIds`

Note that it's an array of up to 5 values, rather than a single value, so it's specified like `['first', 'second', 'etc']` rather than just `'first'`. Hence the square brackets around `['launch-wizard-29']` below

I also specified a key.

The following is what worked for me

```py
import boto3
REGION = 'ap-southeast-2' 
AMI = 'ami-08e9ad7d527e4e95c'
INSTANCE_TYPE = 't2.small' 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    EC2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=REGION)
    init_script = """<powershell>
powershell "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\ScriptToRunDaily.ps1"
aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids 'curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id'
</powershell>"""
    instance = EC2.run_instances(
        ImageId=AMI,
        InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
        MinCount=1,
        MaxCount=1, 
        InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior='terminate', 
        UserData=init_script,
        KeyName='aws', # Name of a key - I used a key (i.e. pem file) that I used for other instances
        SecurityGroupIds=['launch-wizard-29'] # I copied this from another (running) instance
    )
```